# \amsmath \align \display Please identify log errors

Tags: amsmath, displaystyle, cancel

The mwe code below compiles and produces the desired layout.

However, the log shows 3 errors which I can't find after going through the code several times.

Your assistance identifying the source of these errors is greatly appreciated.

Log errors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

mwe

````
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{framed} %box para
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

%\usepackage{bm}%bold equation
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % removes paragraph indentation

\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Assignment 11-A\&B}
       {}
       {Due 03/23/2023} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
  %\makebox[\textwidth]%{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}\par
  \vspace{4mm}
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf {Simplify each expression.}
    %\par
    %\bigskip

  }}}\par
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}
\setlength{\jot}{1em}  
\begin{document}
\pagetop

\settasks{
    after-item-skip=3em,    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=2em,
    item-indent=3em,
    label=(\arabic*),
    column-sep=2em
}
\begin{tasks}(2)
%Prob #1
\task \(\begin{aligned}[t]
&\dfrac{15n+10}{35} \\
& \hspace{2em}\begin{aligned}[t]
&=\dfrac{5(3n+2)}{7\cdot5} \\
&=\dfrac{\cancel{5}(3n+2)}{7\cdot\cancel{5}} \\
&=\fbox{\dfrac{3n+2}{7}}
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}\)
%Problem #2
\task \(\begin{aligned}[t]
&\dfrac{x^2+8x+15}{x+3} \\
& \hspace{2em}\begin{aligned}[t]
&=\dfrac{(x+3)(x+5)}{(x+3)} \\
&=\dfrac{\cancel{(x+3)}(x+5)}{\cancel{(x+3)}}\\
&=\fbox{{x+5}}
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}\)

%Problem #3

%Problem 4

%Problem 5

%Problem 6
       
\end{tasks}
\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\fbox` is a text-mode macro and assumes its content to be *text*, not math: using `\dfrac` in it leads to the error, though TeX's error recovery manages to give you a more or less correct looking result (though you'll see that spacing is off). Stripping everything unrelated, the problem boils down to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\fbox{\dfrac{3n+2}{7}}$
$\fbox{{x+5}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice, however, that while the second formula doesn't throw any error it's actually wrong, since it's not in math mode. For boxing formulas you should use `amsmath`'s `\boxed`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\boxed{\dfrac{3n+2}{7}}$
$\boxed{x+5}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect fix! Thanks also for your very helpful explanation of ```\fbox``` vs ```\boxed``` . That tip will help me avoid problems with future projects.

Comment: @SiuslawMath You're welcome. `\boxed{...}` uses `\fbox` internally, in fact it is basically just `\fbox{$\displaystyle...$}`.

Comment: At the risk of imposing on your generosity, could you possibly look at this LaTeX project (a step-by-step solution for factoring polynomials). It's a resource for my high school Alg II students. The code is a bit of a mess. Thank you! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679746/amsmath-problems-creating-array-for-synthetic-division