# Expand table for additional columns & use TiKz to draw diagonal circle around like terms

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-arrows, arrays

I'm creating a solution set for my students to assist them with learning how to multiply two polynomials.

The mwe below works for a 2 x 2 table (binomial x binomial).

[image]

But I need to show a binomial multiplied by a trinomial with a circle drawn around the "like terms" as shown below.

[image]

My attempts to expand the number of columns have failed miserably.

Please note that problem #1 (binomial x trinomial) is not reflected in the 2 x 2 image above. Just wanted to show that the existing code works.

So your assistance is greatly appreciated.

mwe

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}

\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}

\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setlength\parindent{1em}

\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Test 2 Review (Units 10 and 11)}
       {}
       {014/03/21} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
\noindent 
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
  
    \bigskip
    \bigskip 
  }}}
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=2em,
          item-indent=3em,
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=2em
          }
\begin{document}

%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](2)
% Prob #1
\task $(3x+2)(5x^2-4x+7)$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]

Use the area model to multiply two polynomials.

\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} 
\hspace{1cm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | }
  \mcc{} & \mcc{\textcolor{red}{$5k$}} & \mcc{\textcolor{red}{$+6$}} \\
    \cline{2-3}
 \textcolor{red}{$k$} & $5k^2$ & $6$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
 \textcolor{red}{$+2$} & $10k$ & $12$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.5cm}
Product $={\color{black} 5k^2+16k+6}$ 
\\

\end{solutionorbox}

\vspace{0.25cm}
% Prob #1
\task $\dfrac{5k^2+10k+24}{6k+12}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
step-by-step solution goes here
\end{solutionorbox}
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/680443/47927

Comment: @JasperHabicht  thanks for the link...I added to my LaTeX notes libe for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go, `fit` and `tikzmark` libraries are your friends ;-) (I used a rotation angle of 35, but you might want to adapt it to your needs)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}

\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}

\everymath{\displaystyle}
\setlength\parindent{1em}

\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Test 2 Review (Units 10 and 11)}
       {}
       {014/03/21} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
\noindent 
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
  
    \bigskip
    \bigskip 
  }}}
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=2em,
          item-indent=3em,
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=2em
          }
\begin{document}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} 

%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](2)
% Prob #1
\task $(3x+2)(5x^2-4x+7)$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]

Use the area model to multiply two polynomials.

\hspace{1cm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | }
  \mcc{} & \mcc{\textcolor{red}{$5k$}} & \mcc{\textcolor{red}{$+6$}} \\
    \cline{2-3}
 \textcolor{red}{$k$} & $5k^2$ & $6$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
 \textcolor{red}{$+2$} & $10k$ & $12$ \\
    \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.5cm}
Product $={\color{black} 5k^2+16k+6}$ 
\\

\end{solutionorbox}

\vspace{0.25cm}
% Prob #1
\task $\dfrac{5k^2+10k+24}{6k+12}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
  step-by-step solution goes here
  
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}  
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c | }
  \mcc{}                & \mcc{\textcolor{red}{$5x^2$}}      & \mcc{\textcolor{red}{$-4x$}}        & \mcc{\textcolor{red}{$+7$}}       \\
  \cline{2-4}
  \textcolor{red}{$3x$} & $15x^2$                            & \tikzmarknode{firstDiagB}{$-12x^2$} & \tikzmarknode{secondDiagA}{$21x$} \\
  \cline{2-4}
  \textcolor{red}{$+2$} & \tikzmarknode{firstDiagA}{$10x^2$} & \tikzmarknode{secondDiagB}{$-8x$}   & $14$
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[draw=red, rotate fit=35, rounded corners, fit=(firstDiagA)(firstDiagB)]{};
    \node[draw=green, rotate fit=35, rounded corners, fit=(secondDiagA)(secondDiagB)]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}                                                                                                                    \\
  \cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}

\end{solutionorbox}
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful solution...love the way you used 2 colors to encircle the like terms...very helpful for my students. Thanks for being so generous with your knowledge! At the risk of imposing on your generosity, could you possibly look at this non-compiling code (another solution set for my students): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679746/amsmath-problems-creating-array-for-synthetic-division